# How to correctly store C#'s Bitarray in Postgres table

Tags: c#, postgresql, bitarray

Currently I am trying to store bit patterns of variable length in a Postgres table. My use-case is that I want to encode some information about data records being assigned to groups in a compact way.

A simplified schema of my table in Postgres looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE axivas.group_records (
id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
record_id int4 NOT NULL,
group_ids varbit(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT group_records_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

In a C# application, I create enties using Npgsql Entity FrameworkCore like this:

```
try
{
     var context = new xerxesdevtestsContext();

     Random rnd = new Random();

     for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
     {

        BitArray ba = new BitArray(rnd.Next(10, 50));
        ba.SetAll(false);
        for (int j=rnd.Next(0,5);j<rnd.Next(5,ba.Length-1);j++)
        {
            ba[j] = true;
        }
        context.GroupRecords.Add(new GroupRecords()
        {
            GroupIds = ba,
            RecordId = i
        });

     }
     context.SaveChanges();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
 }
```

Randomnes was added on porpose both for number of set bits and length of the bit array.

When I look at the stored data, I can see that in some cases bit strings are stored with leading zeros, in other cases, leading zeros are omitted (I attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb4ej.png) to show this). In otherwords, in some cases DBeaver shows values like '0000110110111110000.....', in other cases values like '1100111...'.

So my question is, how this can be explained and if there's away to completely omit leading zeros in the bit strings?

Any idea or extra information would be appreciated.

**Update**:
I changed the size of the bit string in my table and

the algorithm which sets individual bits in the bit array a bit and tested again. My changes have the following effects:

1. the bit array will be filled starting from the highest index.
2. in the results event more leading zeros can be observed; e.g. this is one of the resulting records:

> |3104       |702        |0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111110         |

I think this situation clearly demonstrates, why I want leading zeros to be omitted.

Best regards,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems pretty obvious that the reason your bit arrays have leading zeros is because in your `for` loop, `j` is being initialized to some value that is rarely zero. `j` would always have to be zero in order to start placing 1's at the beginning of the array. Otherwise, you are in most cases going to end up with leading zeros.

So, if you want random binary numbers of a variable length, why not do something like this:

```
BitArray ba = new BitArray(rnd.Next(10, 50));

ba.SetAll(false);
ba[0] = true;

for (int j = 1; j < ba.Length - 1; j++)
{
    ba[j] = Convert.ToBoolean(rnd.Next(2));
}
```

Example values created:

```
100110101001000011111100110100010101100110110
111101100110001101001100111101001100011110
1010101111000100
1011001010001000010100
101001101001010100101110000001000111001010
```

Comment: Yes for the C# side of the problem this is obvious. Actually, on the C# side, leading zeros have been generated on purpose to be able to check, how Postgres stores bit strings. Maybe I should have been more precise. I was wondering why PostgreSQL stored leading zeros. They do not carry any information of value, so my understanding was, they were not stored, when varbit is used as data type in a column. However it seems that any bit specified will be stored and the length of the varbit field only defines a maximum length.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @NightFlyer35 yes that was confusing. Your real question could have been quite simply "why does PostgreSQL store leading zeros in a varbit column." You could have hidden the fact that C# was involved at all, and just shown a couple of examples where you were manually inserting binary sequences into the database. And in answer to the question, `varbit` isn't making any claims to be a binary number representation, it is just claiming to hold bit sequences. I believe we would legitimately want leading zeros in some cases.

Comment: sorry for the confusion @robbpriestley. Your comments in mind, I solved my problem using a little helper class which takes care of correct lengths of bit fields.